# Flux.jl: How to sample random batch in dataloader?

Tags: machine-learning, julia, flux.jl

I'm trying to randomly sample a mini-batch from Flux.dataloader rather than iterate through... I already created train_dataloader object, and all I need is random sampling from this object. Can you help me do this? I tried to look up the source code of dataloader in https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/master/src/data/dataloader.jl but I couldn't figure it out. The code below is what I'm trying to do:

```
train_loader = DataLoader((X, L), batchsize=batch_size, shuffle=true)
(x, l) = train_loader[rand(1:length(train_loader))]
```

Comment: What *exactly* is the issue with the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Basically train_loader is not for indexing, so I had to create a function that does this. Thus I looked up the source code, especially in https://github.com/FluxML/Flux.jl/blob/7f375aa46fbdece7ae501f920c12003e9fdf2682/src/data/dataloader.jl#L89. However I am totally new to Julia & Flux.jl so I am not sure what d.nobs, d.indices, and _getobs(d.data, ids) are and how they are working. Especially for the __getobs(), I'm not even sure if both two lines are needed for my function.

Comment: And I thought there could be a simpler way to do this rather than utilizing the code there

Comment: Since it's shuffled, why select any but the first element? `first(DataLoader(...` will be different each time.

Answer (score 0):

I solved in ad hoc method...
I just created an array that holds batches, and randomly selected batches from that array.

```
batch_collection = []
for (x, l) in train_loader
    push!(batch_collection, (x,l))
end

random_batch = rand(batch_collection, 1)[1]
```

Comment: That code is equivalent to `rand(collect(train_loader))`.

Comment: For randomized epochs, you could so something like `Iterators.repeated(shuffle!(collect(train_loader)))`.